# Proving Map is Well-defined

Tags: group-theory

Okay so I have this question:

> Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $N$ and $K$ are normal subgroups
>   of $G$, where $N \leq K$. Define a map: $\theta:G/N \rightarrow G/K$ 
>   by  $\theta(aN)=aK$. Show that $\theta$ is well defined.

I know that in order to show a map is well defined, I have to show that $x_1=x_2 \implies \theta(x_1)=\theta(x_2)$. So for this question, is it a case of proving $aN_1 = aN_2 \implies aK_1=aK_2$? I've proved maps are well defined in the past, but I just don't understand the question  here, can someone explain what it is I have to prove please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost it. What you actually want to do is show that $a_1N=a_2N$ implies that $a_1K=a_2K$, since the inputs into $\theta$ are different left cosets of $N$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll get to work on the proof.

Comment: You're very welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to prove is that the map is *independent of choice of representative*. This is what is usually meant by well-defined. Notice that you picked a specific group element $a$ in the definition of $\theta$. Since everything in $aN$ is "equivalent", $\theta(aN)$ should be the same as $\theta(bN)$ if $aN=bN$. That is, if you pick two different representatives $a$ and $b$, you get the same result. That $N$ is a subgroup of $K$ is important here.

Comment: Of course :) glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Since $N$ and $K$ are fixed (i.e. there are no $N_1, N_2$), you rather have to show $$a_1N=a_2N\implies a_1K=a_2K.$$

Comment: I knew I was barking up the wrong tree, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit iffy but I think you can say:

aN, bN are in N so (ab^-1)N is in N

aN = bN so (ab^-1) = 1

θ((ab^-1)N)=(ab^-1)K = aK.(b^-1)K

But as (ab^-1) = 1, θ((ab^-1)N) = θ(1) = 1 (identity element is the same as N is subgroup of K)

So aK.(b^-1)K = θ((ab^-1)N) = 1

so aK = bK

Sorry about my bad formatting, no idea how to do it on this forum!

Comment: Add a dollar symbol around any text ([MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) you want parsing.

Thanks for the proof, but I ended up doing it a slightly different way:

$a_1N = a_2N \iff y^{-1}x \in N$ hence $y^{-1}x \in K$ as $N \le K \implies x_1K=x_2K$

(Hope that formats correctly, I don't have a live preview so fingers crossed)

Comment: Thanks =) How's other theriault q's going? I'm really finding this one much harder than the last one! No idea how to show that this is an epimorphism!

Comment: Awful! This coursework has just about killed me and at this rate I'll be pulling an all nighter (answered about 30% so far). I've seen [someone else](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051658/dihedral-group-d14-conjugancy-and-subgroups) ask for help on the first question so it looks like there's a few of us who are struggling. I'm working on the epimorphism proof now and I'll post it here if I can work it out :)

Comment: I've done all of 1 (though my subgroup lattice is looking rather sparse) I think so if you need any help with that just ask =)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm working through 2 now but I'll certainly take you up on that one in a bit.
Epimorphism: Any coset of M can be written as $xM$ for $x \in G$, and $xM=\theta(xN)$

Comment: How did you find the conjugacy classes and subgroups? I can find them for a symmetric group but I'm really struggling for this dihedral one.

Comment: for the conjugacy classes look at exercise sheet 6, exercise 6. I got {1}, {o,o6}, {o2,o5}, {o3,o4} and (r,or,o2r,o3r,o4r,o5r,o6r} for mine. Subgroups I just put down D14, {1} and the groups generated by o and r (<o>,<r>) but I'm sure there are supposed to be more but I can't find out how to get them! Everything else seems to generate the entire group

Comment: Thanks so much mystery coursemate, I hadn't seen question 6. Any idea how to show 2b is a homomorphism? I've nearly done all of 2, but I'm stuck on that last little bit.

Comment: Oh I just said 0(abN)=abK=aK.bK (by the binary operation for quotient groups) =0(aN).0(bN) thus proving 0(abN)=0(aN)0(bN) which is the necessary condition for a homomorphism. I'm completely stumped on the last question though so any help there would be much appreciated!

Comment: Still working on that, but have a look here for a few tips:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052291/using-the-third-isomorphism-theorem/1052407?noredirect=1#comment2142890_1052407

I'll post a solution here if I get to it :)

Comment: Forgot to say, thanks for the homomorphism proof! I'm an idiot for missing that, I was doing o(aNbN)=aKbK lol.

Comment: Good luck for tomorrow! Hope you did well in the coursework btw.