# Using the Third Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: group-theory

Here's my question

> Using the Third Isomorphism Theorem, show that if m, n are positive
>   integers then there is an isomorphism:
>
> $\Bbb Z_m \cong \Bbb Z_{mn}/\Bbb Z_{n}$

I began this by assuming $m \ge n$ so I can apply the Third Isomorphism Theorem to see that:

1. <s>$\Bbb Z_m / \Bbb Z_n $ is a normal subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{mn} / \Bbb Z_n$</s>
2. $(\Bbb Z_{mn} / \Bbb Z_n)(\Bbb Z_m / \Bbb Z_n) $ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{mn} / \Bbb Z_n$

As $\Bbb Z_n \subseteq \Bbb Z_m \subseteq \Bbb Z_{mn}$

But I don't even know where to begin proving this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you have a typo. Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}_{m} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{mn}/\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Comment: I do, thank you! I've edited my post.

Comment: Your first point seems fishy considering you don't even necessarily have $\mathbb{Z}_n \leq \mathbb{Z}_m$, let alone $\mathbb{Z}_n \unlhd \mathbb{Z}_m$. E.g., is $\mathbb{Z}_3 \leq \mathbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: My mistake, I've removed that. Thank you for your reply!